# JS bind the context of a function before passing

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to setup a function that stores a callback which can be fired later on an event, but I'm not getting the context to bind right. The setup is basically like this:

```
app.myObject = function(){
  this.bindEvents();
};
app.myObject.prototype = {
  bindEvents: function(){
    var self = this;
    this.library = new OutsideLibrary();
    this.library.onMyEvent = function(data) {
      OtherLibrary.processData(data, self.runCallback); // I'm not able to pass a context here...
    }
  },
  sendToLibrary: function(message,callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    this.library.send(message);
  }
  // ... and this doesn't work because it gets evaluated in the wrong context.
  runCallback: function() { 
    if (this.callback) {
      this.callback();
      this.callback = null;
    }
  }
}
```

I hope the above code makes sense. The idea is, I'm trying to expose an API where I can call:

```
app.myObject.sendToLibrary("something", function() {...});
```

...and the callback function will run after the whole chain is complete.

The problem is, I can't pass the callback that is received in `sendToLibrary` directly through, because the callback need to be passed to another object when an event fires. Also since I'm having to store the currently passed callback, and the callback is optional, I need to unset it once it has fired, so I actually need to pass the `runCallback` function to run the callback once then unset it.

Anyway, the problem is that when `runCallback` eventually gets executed it is no longer in the correct context, so it doesn't work. My first idea for how to fix this was to change the `runCallback` function to include a context argument, so I could pass `self.runCallback(self)` -- but that executes immediately so it defeats the purpose.

Anyway, I'm sort of lost in the callback woods here, and would appreciate some help finding my way out :)

My question is: is there a way to wrap up a callback function and the correct context, without executing it now, so that when it eventually fires it does so from the correct context?

Thanks!

Comment: `I'm not able to pass a context here` Can't you use `.call(context)` syntax to call `runCallback`?

Comment: As I understand it, `.call()` executes the function immediately, whereas I need to pass it along, not yet executed, so that `OtherLibrary` will execute it when it is finished with its stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OtherLibrary.processData(data, function() {
    self.runCallback();
)};
```

Then inside of `runCallback` `this` refers to an instance of `app.myObject`, if this is what you want.

Comment: *facepalm*. Yeah, it's that simple.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew, I think you might be trying a little too hard, here.

If all you're looking to do is bind context, you can do one of the following:

```
var working_method = context.method.bind(context);
// bind is IE9+, and does something similar to the below

// or, from whatever scope your context/method are available in, define this function
var working_method = function () { context.method(); };
```

If you require parameters, and you already know the footprint:

```
var working_method = function (a, b, c) { context.method(a, b, c); };
```

The solution for variable argument lengths (ie: a generalized "bind" method) is longer, but if you're defining stuff in line, what I've got here might be all you need.

Just make sure that you do not use `this` in your wrapping function (whether you save it to a var, or pass it directly into another function), because it will reference `window`.

Comment: That's the problem with IE: you think something's supported, but it never is ;)

Comment: Hah. In my defense that was actually a problem with my brain, because I just finished handling an XHR issue over e-mail, and didn't bother switching back into event-handler mode. While IE is totally to blame for not getting anything right, and for staggering fixing XHR and events/callbacks, it's on me to pay attention to which I'm dealing with.

Comment: Hey Norguard, you're right, I was way over-thinking this. Thanks for the input. I'm going to actually use zeroflagL's method (which makes me want to punch myself in the head...), but I really appreciate your example!

Comment: No worries. They're all the exact same coin. Make a function which uses a variable that's available in whatever scope you're defining the function in, and then call the method on it. There might be times where you need to get a little more complex, but really, they're few and far between.